# Ned Help Converting to SQL

Tags: sql

HI Having trouble figuring this out. Can Someone help me convert this to SQL? Im trying to just select a specific sentence from various fields.

```
numberVar BegPos := 0;
numberVar EndPos := 0;

BegPos := InStr ({HEADER_MSG.MEMO_PAD1} ,'STATUS:',1);
IF BegPos >= 1 THEN
EndPos := InStr (begpos,{HEADER_MSG.MEMO_PAD1} ,'.');

IF NOT ISNULL({HEADER_MSG.MEMO_PAD1}) THEN

(
BegPos := BegPos + 7;

IF (BegPos <= 0 OR EndPos <= 0) or BegPos = EndPos THEN
" "
ELSE
Mid ({HEADER_MSG.MEMO_PAD1},BegPos, Endpos - Begpos) 

)
ELSE
" "
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

so you have a field that has Status:samplestatus. and you want it to return everything inbetween the first : and . i.e.

```
Samplestatus
```

Substring() and PatIndex() will be useful.

```
substring(HEADER_MSG.MEMO_PAD1, PatIndex('Status%',HEADER_MSG.MEMO_PAD1)+7, PatIndex('%.%',HEADER_MSG.MEMO_PAD1)-8)
```

where HEADER_MSG.MEMO_PAD1 is your field.

```
Select substring(Data, PatIndex('Status%', Data)+7, PatIndex('%.%', Data)-8)
from(
select 'Status: testStatus2.' as Data
)x
```

returns

```
testStatus2
```